# display the current user's username in a component angular7

Tags: angular

I created in the authentication service a subject that emits the whole data of the user.
In the header component i subscribed to that observable. and everything should works fine, but it's not displaying any data.
This is the autoAuth function in the auth service.

```
autoAuthUser() {
      const authInformation = this.getAuthData();
      if (!authInformation) {
        return;
      }
        this.authStatusListener.next(true);
        this.fetchUser(authInformation.userId).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            if (res.user) {
              this.currentUser = res.user;
              this.userListener.next(this.currentUser);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

and this is in the header component:

```
this.authService.autoAuthUser();
        this.authService.getAuthStatusListener().subscribe((isA) => {
            this.isAuthenticated = isA;
            if (this.isAuthenticated) {
            this.authService.getUserListener().subscribe(
            (user) => {
                this.currentUser = user;
            }
        );
      }
```

this is in the template of the header component:

```
<p class="username">{{currentUser?.username}}</p>
```

when i console log the current user in the header component, i got the whole the correct data but it's not displaying anything.

Comment: do you have an ngIf flag in parent html element

Comment: no, actually when i try to display a simple string, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the header component move the `this.authService.autoAuthUser();` call at the bottom.

This should work

```
this.authService.getUserListener().subscribe((user) => {
    this.currentUser = user;
});

this.authService.getAuthStatusListener().subscribe((isA) => {
    this.isAuthenticated = isA;
});

this.authService.autoAuthUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write authService as follows, but I am not sure if you need both authStatusListener & userListener. If userLister sends **null** then you can assume auth status as false.

```
autoAuthUser() {
  const authInformation = this.getAuthData();
  if (!authInformation) {
    // need to set false if user not found.
    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
    this.userListener.next(null);
    return;
  }
  this.authStatusListener.next(true);
  this.fetchUser(authInformation.userId).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      if (res.user) {
        this.currentUser = res.user;
        this.userListener.next(this.currentUser);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

And change header component as

```
this.authService.autoAuthUser();
this.authService.getAuthStatusListener().subscribe((isA) => {
  this.isAuthenticated = isA;
  if (this.isAuthenticated) {
    this.authService.getUserListener().subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.currentUser = user;
      }
    );
  }
});
```